# i want to add ion-item after an ion option is selected in ion-select

Tags: ionic-framework

As different option has different information to input I want to ask how can I have additional ion-item after an option is selected from ion-select.

These are my codes:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label class="lbReward" color="dark" >Reward Type:  </ion-label>
    <ion-select (ionChange) = "onChange()" okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss" placeholder= "Select Type" formControlName = "rewardType" [ngModel] = "selectedRewardType">
        <ion-option value="priceDiscount">Total Price Discount</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="categoryDiscount">Category Price Discount</ion-option> 
        <ion-option value="freeGiftwithPrice">Sufficient Price Free Gift</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="freeGiftwithMeal">Meal with Free Gift</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label color="dark" >Discount Percentage:  </ion-label>
    <ion-input name= "discountPercent" type="text" formControlName = "discountPercent"> </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

I want to show the Discount Percentage only after I select Total Price Discount. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

Add `*ngIf` statement to your `<ion-item>`

```
<ion-item *ngIf="selectedRewardType && selectedRewardType.length > 0">
    <ion-label color="dark" >Discount Percentage:  </ion-label>
    <ion-input name= "discountPercent" type="text" formControlName = "discountPercent"> </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Oh did you use two-way binding like `[(ngModel)] = "selectedRewardType"`? Not like `[ngModel] = "selectedRewardType"` which you wrote in question.